# exclude from table if !=

Tags: r

If I'm using the `table()` I can exclude elements by doing:

```
b <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10))
table(b, exclude="B")
```

Now what if I want to exclude everything but "B"?

I have tried 
`table(b, exlcude=!"B")` but it hasn't worked. does the `table()` function allow this functionality?

Comment: If you don't fix this question, you risk it being closed.  Which `table` argument?  To which function? If you post some example code and expected results maybe somebody can help.

Comment: think they mean table 'function' - edited.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to first gather all the possible levels in the particular factor variable(s) that has(have) a level "B". There are probably easier ways to do this, but assuming the factor in which the desired exclusion occurs is 'fac1' then perhaps something like:

```
with( datafrm, table(fac1, fac2, fac3, exclude=setdiff(levels(fac1), "B") ) )
```

I would probably have done it less "double negatively" with `subset`:

```
with(subset( datafrm, fac1 == "B"), table(fac1, fac2, fac3) )
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If "B" is included, setdiff("B",levels(fac1)) is character(0). You have to turn them around : setdiff(levels(fac1), "B")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setdiff`:

```
table(iris$Species,exclude=setdiff(iris$Species,"virginica"))    
virginica 
       50
```

Of course, you may as well just subset your table object:

```
table(iris$Species)["virginica"]
virginica 
       50
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
table(b)['B']
```

But for counting occurences of one value, there's no need to use table. Much simpler is this:

```
sum(b=='B')
```